# ForiegnKey field serializer in Django Rest framework

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

Before posting this question I've read few questions on SOF. but they are from 2012 and very confusing as well.
for e.g [Django Rest Framework - Get related model field in serializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633313/django-rest-framework-get-related-model-field-in-serializer)

my question is very straight forward

models.py

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=False,blank=False)

class Car(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    car_name = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True,blank=True)
```

serializers.py

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','password' )

class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #user = ?? what should I write or is there any better approach for serializing Car objects
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('user','car_name')
```

views.py

```
class UserViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = UserSerializer

class CarViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Car.objects.all()
    serializer_class = CarSerializer
```

Please suggest all possible approaches.

1 more query. which one is better `ModelSerializer` or `HyperlinkModelSerializer`. as I saw different different answers containing these two.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to do:

```
class CarSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Car
        fields = ('user','car_name')
```

that is all.

Also, you should take a look to the kindnesses of `serializers.Field` and `serializers.SerializerMethodField`, you can play with them and customize your response data as much as you wish.

As to the question around `HyperlinkedModelSerializer`-`ModelSerializer`, very clear [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/5-relationships-and-hyperlinked-apis):

The `HyperlinkedModelSerializer` has the following differences from `ModelSerializer`:

- It does not include the pk field by default.
- It includes a url field, using `HyperlinkedIdentityField`.
- Relationships use `HyperlinkedRelatedField`, instead of `PrimaryKeyRelatedField`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I'm using django_restframeowrk's default interface and when I click on cars url its showing me error for user field `non_field_errors`. what is this?