# Django REST Framework asks for related model's id when it's already in the POST parameters

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Using Django and its REST_Framework, I'm trying to add an object to my POSTGRES-11 database, whose model (Team) is related to another model (Country) by a ForeignKey relation. The JSON I send with the post request looks like this, where the number provided for country is supposed to be its id.

```
name:"test"
is_onsite:true
status:"PAID"
institution:"testU"
country:2
```

But then Django returns the following error:

```
IntegrityError at /api/register/team/
null value in column "country_id" violates not-null constraint
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (28, , f, PENDING, , null).
```

I've tried sending the same json with 'country' replaced with 'country_id', but I've been faced with the same error.

I've already tried the solution given [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20633313/django-rest-framework-get-related-model-field-in-serializer), but then Django returns this JSON instead of adding the object:

```
{
    "country": [
        "This field is required."
    ]
}
```

models.py:

```
class Country(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    flag = models.ImageField()
    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'Countries'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Team(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="", blank=True)
    is_onsite = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=TEAM_STATUS_CHOICES, default='PENDING')
    institution = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="")
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default="", blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py:

```
class CountrySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Country 
        fields = '__all__'

class TeamSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Team 
        fields = ['name', 'is_onsite', 'status', 'institution', 'country']
```

views.py:

```
class TeamCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Team.objects.all()
    serializer_class = TeamSerializer
```

I should note that Django works perfectly fine when I try to add it via the HTML form provided at '/api/register/team', but not when it receives a JSON via outer post requests.

I've been stuck at this for days, so your help would be really appreciated.

---

@dirkgroten
I forgot to mention, I did the former thing by adding the following snippet to my TeamSerializer and tried sending the 'countryId' (and not 'country_id') in my POST request, but it still didn't work.
This snippet:

```
countryId = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Country.objects.all())
    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data)
        return Team.objects.create(
            name=validated_data['name'],
            is_onsite=validated_data['is_onsite'],
            status=validated_data['status'],
            institution=validated_data['institution'],
            country=validated_data['countryId']
        )
```

As for the latter case, I added the 
`country = CountrySerializer(many=False)` line to my code, and sent a JSON like the following, but I still got the "This field is required" JSON.
My POST JSON:

```
name:"test"
is_onsite:true
status:"PAID"
institution:"testU"
country:{"name": "Test"}
```

Even though the country 'Test' exists in my database, it still fails to add the team.

Comment: You sure there is a country with id `2` in your database? Also remove `default` from the model, if default is provided drf will not check for not null.

Comment: Yep, pretty sure.
"[
    {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "Test",
        "flag": "http://localhost:8000/api/photo.jpg"
    }
]"

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should remove `default="", blank=True` on your `country` field for the `Team` model. FK fields should never have empty string as default. If you want the possibly for your country to be "unset", use `blank=True, null=True`. But if every `Team` always must have a country, then don't add anything.

You can do two things:

- Either you use `'country_id'` in the fields of your `TeamSerializer` and pass the field as `country_id` in your JSON. You need to do both, passing `country_id` in your JSON but `country` as field in the serializer won't work.

  ```
  fields = ['name', 'is_onsite', 'status', 'institution', 'country_id']
  ```
- Or you add `country = CountrySerializer(many=False)` to your `TeamSerializer` but then in your json, you need to nest a country inside your request and it will create the country object:

  ```
  {'name': 'test',
   ...
   'country': {
       'name': 'Angola'
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: but `countryId` doesn't match `country_id` from your POST. And "latter" means my second option, I don't see how your code relates to my second option. My first option is just to set `fields = ['country_id', ...]`

Comment: I know it doesn't match, it was for a previous version where I named it 'countryId' and sent the request with a parameter named 'countryId', which gave the exact same "This field is required" response.